# Where should I implement the equivalent of a 'base.html' in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am transitioning from a Flask backend without a front end framework to Vue.js (no backend chosen yet).

Previously I would create a base.html file that would contain all the boilerplate html code and dependencies (like links to stylesheets), javascript dependencies (like the j-query library) as well as html components of my website that should be included on every page (like the nav bar, background image e.t.c). Then, using the jinja2 templating language I would extend base.html in every subsequent page.

I would like to do something similar with Vue but am not sure where to implement this 'base.html' sort of code. Here is the file structure of my vue js project, I used the vue cli to create this project:

[image: File Structure]

I was thinking I could either put the html contents of what was previously 'base.html' in the index.html file (all the way at the bottom of the picture) or in the template of the src/App.vue file.. or perhaps there just a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If your background on backend is Flask I'd suggest you to keep on using it and use Vue for your frontend.

Said that I think that there are countless good examples about how to integrate Flask with Vue, here's an interesting one from GitHub: [flask-vuejs-template](https://github.com/gtalarico/flask-vuejs-template).